# HTML5 - Section don't set its height automatically to components inside, but sets its height as span height

Tags: html, height, figure

The **section** in my HTML project contains **h2**, **span** and **figure** with img inside.
h2 is the header of section and figure and span are floated (e.g figure at the left and span at the right side).

The layout visually is OK, but when I inspect elements in the browser the section sets its height as span's height and the figure overflows outside the section (As I say - visually elements don't overlap but the real section height is wrong).

It causes a problem for me because my page has a few sections one below another and I need to refer to the specific sections via navigation links and it leads me to not accurate place in the page.

Why section doesn't set its real height automatically to height all elements inside?
In his case, how to force section to have the height of all containing elements instead of having span's height?

```
                <section class="sec1">
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <figure class="figureLeft">
                    <img src="picture.jpg" width="250" height="300" />
                    <figcaption><i>Picture</i></figcaption>
                </figure>
                <span>A few lines of text inside the span....
                </span>
               </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the elements for the problem to be resolved.

You can upgrade from:

```
display:inline-block;
height: auto;
```